# Cannot install kubectl on Ubuntu - GPG Error

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kubectl

Hi I'm trying to install `kubectl` following the native package install instructions on the [official site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-using-native-package-management), but I get the following error when I try to update apt package list before installing `kubectl`:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
E: The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial InRelease' is not signed.
```

What could be the issue? `ca-certificates` and `apt-transport-https` are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the current stable release 22.04, the step 2, *Download the Google Cloud public signing key*, is missing the `gpg --dearmor` command that is now needed for signing keys.

Replace step 2 with this command:

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | \
  sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg
```

<sup>(shamelessly adapted from the Docker installation instructions)</sup>